# PIP error at ArchWSL while installing packages

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux, archlinux

Setting up NeoVim at ArchWSL while running the batch command:

```
bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lunarvim/lunarvim/master/utils/installer/install.sh)
```

It gets stuck in the specific python installation, throwing the following error:

```
Would you like to install LunarVim's Python dependencies: pynvim?
[y]es or [n]o (default: no) : y
Verifying that pip is available..
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
    python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.

    If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
    installed via pacman.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    sys.exit(ensurepip._main())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 286, in _main
    return _bootstrap(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 202, in _bootstrap
    return _run_pip([*args, *_PACKAGE_NAMES], additional_paths)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 103, in _run_pip
    return subprocess.run(cmd, check=True).returncode
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/sbin/python3', '-W', 'ignore::DeprecationWarning', '-c', '\nimport runpy\nimport sys\nsys.path = [\'/tmp/tmpz1z3dzgs/setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl\', \'/tmp/tmpz1z3dzgs/pip-23.2.1-py3-none-any.whl\'] + sys.path\nsys.argv[1:] = [\'install\', \'--no-cache-dir\', \'--no-index\', \'--find-links\', \'/tmp/tmpz1z3dzgs\', \'setuptools\', \'pip\']\nrunpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)\n']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

running pip list I've got:

```
Package      Version
------------ -------
attrs        22.2.0
cffi         1.15.1
cryptography 41.0.3
packaging    23.1
pip          23.2.1
ply          3.11
pycparser    2.21
wheel        0.40.0
```

I've used the python virtual environment to manually install pynvim what seems to have proceed successfully, how do I fix it?